# Most efficient/idiomatic way to test a 256-bit YMM AVX register for zero

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, x86-64, micro-optimization

I have an x86_64 routine which eventually ends up with zero in a YMM register if it was successful, and I'd like to return non-zero if the YMM register.

I have a way to do it by clearing another YMM register, VPTEST'ing my register against that one, and then conditionally incrementing the resturn register (RAX in my case) if CF is not set:

```
"    xor    %%rax,   %%rax              \n" // clear RAX

"    vxorpd %%ymm0,  %%ymm0,    %%ymm0  \n" // clear YMM0
"    vptest %%ymm1,  %%ymm0             \n" // compare YMM1 to zero

"    jc     endcheck                    \n" // branch over if no residue
"    inc    %%rax                       \n" // inc RAX otherwise

"endcheck:                              \n" // result is now in RAX
```

This seems like a slightly opaque way to do it. Is there a better way, or a more idiomatic or readable way?

Comment: You don't need two YMM registers with one cleared - just do `vptest %%ymm1, %%ymm1`

Comment: @PaulR, thanks, that helps. I then use `jz` in that case to identify zero.

Comment: Also you should favor branchless code, you can use `SETC`/`SETNC` or even `ADC`/`SBB`.

Comment: there's no extended assembly here, why do you put it in strings like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining the comments above, it can be done in three lines of assembly:

```
"xor         %%rax,      %%rax    \n" // clear RAX
"vptest      %%ymm1,     %%ymm1   \n" // if YMM1 zero, set ZF
"setnz       %%al                 \n" // set byte in RAX if not zero
```

This seems much clearer and more like what I had in mind.